# Rails :counter_cache with custom query association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, database-performance

I have a model like this:

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :content, counter_cache: true
end

class Content
  has_many :votes
  has_many :votes_up, -> { where(positive: true) }, class_name: 'Vote'
  has_many :votes_down, -> { where(positive: false) }, class_name: 'Vote'
end
```

If I create a proper migration, when I execute `mycontent.votes_count`, it will not make a query.

But what about `mycontent.votes_up.count` and `mycontent.votes_down.count`? Can I cache them in the same (simple) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an out of the box rails solution for this so I think it will take some custom code. It should be very straightforward and only involve adding some callbacks to `Vote` and two cache columns to `Content`. You can view available callbacks here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

I think adding an `after_save` and `after_destroy` to `Vote` would do the trick.

You might also look at this gem: https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture it might have something that would help.

But basically you can just add some callbacks to `Vote` and increment/decrement two custom counters yourself.

Comment: counter_culture is great for this! Thank you

Comment: @ProGM can you tell how did you solve this with counter_culture gem?